# Relation between curvature and sectional curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, connections

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $ h = c.g$ for some $c > 0$ . Then the Levi-Civita connections of $g$ and $h$ are same.
From the above deduce the relation between corresponding curvature and sectional curvature.

I am able to solve the first part, i.e  the Levi-Civita connections are same. But I am unable to solve the second part, i.e the relation between two curvature.
Need some help.

Comment: Do you know the formula for the curvatures?

Comment: Yes I know that..

Comment: Then it should get the expression, as the curvature are given by $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ and $g^{kl}$, and you know that $\Gamma$ is the same while $h^{kl} = c^{-1} g^{kl}$.

Comment: I know that sectional curvature $K(p)= R(x,y,x,y)/( |x|^2.|y|^2 - <x,y>^2)$ but I don't know the formula using Christoffel symbols

Comment: So how do you define $R(x, y, z, w)$?

Comment: $R(x,y,z,w)=<R(x,y,z) , w>$

Comment: Yes.... But then what is $R(x, y, z)$?

Comment: Ok.. $R(X,Y,Z)= \bigtriangledown_Y(\bigtriangledown_X(Z)) - \bigtriangledown_X(\bigtriangledown_Y(Z)) + \bigtriangledown_[X,Y](Z) $

Comment: Cool, so $R(X, Y, Z)$ is not changed as $\nabla$ is not changed. So you only need to change the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$.

Comment: Ok. Is there something multiplied by $1/c^2$

Comment: You need only to represent $\frac{h( R (x, y, x), y)}{ h(x, x)h(y, y) - h(x, y)^2}$ by that of $g$.

Comment: $h(x,x)=c.g(x,x)$.So there is $c^2$ in the denominator.Is this right?

Comment: Yes, and that's a $c$ on top.

Comment: but curvature remains same.so why there is a $c$ on the top?

Comment: Cause there's a $h$ on the top.

Comment: oo...I thought $R(x.y,x,y)$ remains unchanged..I forgot that there is an inner product..Now it's fine.Thank you

Comment: The curvature of the sphere of radius $R$ is $1\over R^2$. Multipliying the metric by $c$ divides the curvature by $c^2$. The case of the 2-sphere is enough, as you are just looking in the direction of a plane $P$, and the 2-tensor discribing the metri in an exponential chart and resticted to a plane is the same up to the order 2 as a sphere with the same curvature (standard geometric interpretation of curvature).